# Passing string/JSON from C# to JS using CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, json, wpf, cefsharp

I have an html page, which I want to host in my C# application (WPF).
since I need the browser to be Chromium based I'm using cefSharp.

I want to pass string data from C# to the JS for the page's initialization.

I found `RegisterJsObject` which lets me access a C# object from JS,  but I can't seem to pass any string information from it.

My code currently looks something like this:

C#:

```
mainWindow.browser.RegisterJsObject("csobj", "a string");
```

JS:

```
...
console.log(JSON.stringify(window.csobj)); //I get an empty obj {}
```

I've also tried to define my own object with a `public string GetJson()` method,  but then JS doesn't recognize it as a function, I assume because it expects a `public void` signature.

Is there a way to do this?

For the record I'm actually trying to pass a long list of words for auto-complete purposes, so it won't be just a simple 'string'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem in your code:**
You are not registering Js Object properly and that's why you are not able to get the object in JS.

**Guidelines:**

RegisterJsObject is to register your c# object and then call those methods from JS and send values from JS to c#.

If you want to pass empty string from c# to your HTML page then you should register JS object like below:

Your c# class should be as shown below:

```
public class AsyncBoundObject
{
    //We expect an exception here, so tell VS to ignore
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public void Error()
    {
        throw new Exception("This is an exception coming from C#");
    }

    //We expect an exception here, so tell VS to ignore
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public int Div(int divident, int divisor)
    {
        return divident / divisor;
    }
}
```

Then you can register this class in CefSharp instance as shown below:

```
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("boundAsync", new AsyncBoundObject());
```

After they are registered, you can call the method from JS as shown below.

```
function asyncDivOk()
{
    var call = "Async call (Divide 16 / 2): " + Date();
    window.boundAsync.div(16, 2).then(function (res)
    {
        var end = "Result: " + res + "(" + Date() + ")";
        writeAsyncResult(call, end);
    });
}
```

You can see 16 and 2 are the parameters which are being passed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  but I can't seem to get your example to work-  for me it throws "Uncaught TypeError: window.boundAsync.div(...).then is not a function".  any idea how to fix this?

Comment: nvm -It was a captalization issue,  works perfectly! thank you!